# How to produce comment in an adjacent column based on the difference between 2 values in a separate column

Tags: r

I want to produce a comment in an adjacent column based on the difference between the lag and lead values. I'm not sure where to start, how do I do that? I want my data to look like this:

| KP | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| 7.22565 |  |
| 7.22567 |  |
| 7.22668 | Anomaly |
| 7.22456 | Anomaly |

Comment: I forgot to mention, the value is +- 0.001 for the change in value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `lag()` and `lead()` from `dplyr` to calculate a label field based on some test. For example, this code is labeled "Anomaly" if the lag is greater than the lead.

```
KP <-  c(7.22565, 7.22567, 7.22668, 7.22456)
df1 <- data.frame(KP)

#create vector
df1$comment<-""
#use lag() and lead() 
df1$comment[dplyr::lag(df1$KP) > dplyr::lead(df1$KP)]<-"Anomaly"
```

If you just want to flag if the value has changed by more than 0.001 from the lag value you could use:

```
df1$comment<-""
df1$comment[abs(df1$KP - dplyr::lag(df1$KP)) > 0.001] <-"Anomaly"
```

Comment: this worked well cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution.
Create an index telling if the lagged differences are greater than the maximum allowed. That index is then OR'ed (`|`) with the vector of differences computed on the input reversed. Then create a column with all empty strings and assign `"Anomaly"` to the elements given by the index.

The two instructions used to create `i` can be only one but the code is more readable if lag and lead differences are computed separatly.

```r
KP <- scan(text = "7.22565  
7.22567     
7.22668 
7.22456")
df1 <- data.frame(KP)

dmax <- 0.001
i <- c(FALSE, diff(df1$KP) > dmax)
i <- i | c(FALSE, (diff(rev(df1$KP)) > dmax) |> rev())
df1$Comment <- ""
df1$Comment[i] <- "Anomaly"
df1
#>        KP Comment
#> 1 7.22565        
#> 2 7.22567        
#> 3 7.22668 Anomaly
#> 4 7.22456 Anomaly
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>